# Resurrection difference in using Object Initializer

Tags: c#, garbage-collection, finalizer

I have this code:

Essentially i'm trying to demonstrate the use of the c# finalizer and make an object that cannot die, I called it Zombie. Now, normally this demo works great, but today I tried using the same code with the object initializer instead of just assigning to the property (Name in this case). I noticed there is a difference. Namely that the finalizer never gets called, not even when I'm trying my best to make the Garbage Collector do it's work.

Could someone explain the difference, or have I found a bug in the C# compiler?

(I'm using C# 4 in VS2010 SP1 on Win7x64)

Thanks.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;

namespace Zombie
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      Console.WriteLine("Main thread: " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);

              // case 1: this is where the problem is located.
      Zombie z = new Zombie { Name = "Guy" }; // object initializer syntax makes that the finalizer is not called.

              // case 2: this is not causing a problem. The finalizer gets called.
      //Zombie z = new Zombie();
      //z.Name = "Guy";

      WeakReference weakZombieGuyRef = new WeakReference(z, true);

      z = null;

      GC.GetTotalMemory(forceFullCollection: true);

      GC.Collect();

      while (true)
      {

        Console.ReadKey();
        if (weakZombieGuyRef.IsAlive)
        {
          Console.WriteLine("zombie guy still alive");
        }
        else
        {
          Console.WriteLine("Zombie guy died.. silver bullet anyone?");
        }

        Zombie.Instance = null;

        GC.AddMemoryPressure(12400000);
        GC.GetTotalMemory(forceFullCollection: true);

        GC.Collect();
      }


    }
  }

  public class Zombie
  {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public  static Zombie Instance = null;

    ~Zombie()
    {
      Console.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
      Console.WriteLine("Finalizer called on zombie" + this.Name);
      lock (typeof(Zombie))
      {
        Instance = this;

        GC.ReRegisterForFinalize(this);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: When I create the Zombie z in an extra method, then the problem indeed goes away.
        public static Zombie CreateZombie()
    {
      return new Zombie { Name = "Guy" };
    }

Comment: Tried this with VS2012 and .NET 4.5. I could not find any cases where there was a difference between object initializer and "old-style" create-first-then-set-property code. If you do this in Debug mode without optimizations, the `GC` will not collect `z` (that is the object `z` originally referenced) before the method has ended. That's for easier debugging; it won't collect until local variable is out of scope in a formal way (`z` is still in scope near the end of the method). If you extract the first part of `Main` (with `z`) out to a separate method, it will work under Debug build as well.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

EDIT: While the original answer below is still accurate, it looks like it's the mixture of debug information and optimization which makes a difference here.

From my experiments:

```
Compiler flags                        Result
/o+ /debug-                           Finalizer runs
/o+ /debug+                           Finalizer runs
/o- /debug-                           Finalizer runs
/o- /debug+                           Finalizer does *not* run
```

---

The finalizer is still called on my box, when compiling on the command line with `/o+`. My guess is that you're running in a debugger - which changes the GC behaviour. Without the debugger, the GC will collect anything that it can prove will never be read. *With* the debugger, I believe the GC won't collect any objects which still have references on the stack, even if there's no *code* to read the variables in question.

Now with an object initializer, the compiler code includes an extra reference on the stack. This line:

```
Zombie z = new Zombie { Name = "Guy" };
```

is effectively:

```
Zombie tmp = new Zombe();
tmp.Name = "Guy";
Zombie z = tmp;
```

The assignment to `z` is only performed *after* all the properties have been set.

My guess is that the `tmp` variable here is keeping the object alive.

Comment: Thanks for the extremely quick answer. However when I run with or without debugger (F5 or Ctrl-F5) there is no difference. The tmp variable on the stack would indeed explain it.

Comment: @jeroentrappers: Are you building in Debug or Release configuration? (I'm seeing "Finalizer called on zombieGuy" if that's what you're expecting but not seeing...)

Comment: I was building in Debug indeed. When building in Release the problem goes away automatically. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you want objects that don't die, you really don't need to mess with finalizers. Just have a private static list of all instances, and add objects to that list as they are created:

```
class Immortal
{
    static List<Immortal> _immortals = new List<Immortal>();

    public Immortal()
    {
       _immortals.Add(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: I realize that, however the purpose of the demo is to demonstrate the finalizer.