# Immutable type constructor shorthand

Tags: c#

I've got some immutable types in C#. They're basically all just e.g.

```
public class Class : IInterface
{
    public Class(IInterface2 prop1, IInterface2 prop2)
    {
        Property1 = prop1;
        Property2 = prop2;
    }

    public IInterface2 Property1 { get; }
    public IInterface2 Property2 { get; }
}
```

I just found a bug where the two property sets in the constructor were mixed up.

Are there any shorthands for immutable types in C# that can omit or generate this constructor?

I tried e.g.

```
public class Class : IInterface
{
    public readonly IInterface2 Property1;
    public readonly IInterface2 Property2;
}
```

Unfortunately, when I try to use it, such as

```
var f = new Class { Property1 = null, Property2 = null };
```

the compiler shouts at me, saying that readonly fields can't be set except in a constructor or variable initializer, despite the fact that it's clearly a goddamn variable initializer.

Comment: Do you mean a bug in the compiler on in .NET?

Comment: Well, I presume that it's an oversight in the specification that you can't set readonly fields that way.

Comment: Do you get a compile error? Are you using C#6 or an earlier version?

Comment: I'm using VS2015 Update 2, which afaik is the newest available version.

Comment: I am referring to the `bug where the two property sets in the constructor were mixed up`. Is this a bug in your code? Or do you suspect a bug in .NET?

Comment: No, it was a bug in my code. They have compatible types. The point is that I don't want to write the constructor in the first place.

Comment: There is a proposed feature for C# compiler, which might be added already in not so far future: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/features/records/docs/features/records.md. With that feature your type declaration will become just public Class(IInterface2 Property1, IInterface2 Property2);

Comment: That feature covers far more than I'm actually interested in, though ;p

Comment: Well you will have no property sets in Constructor, so no way to mix them up :)

Comment: @Puppy, can you please check one of the answers as the correct one? This can be a useful feedback also for other SO users that see this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no syntax in C# that allows to set read-only properties from outside of the class or auto-generate constructor.

Initializer syntax is just syntax sugar for property set calls - so this is expected behavior and not oversight in specification. This is discussed in [Readonly field in object initializer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18385248/readonly-field-in-object-initializer) question and following MSDN article:

[Object and Collection Initializers (C# Programming Guide)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx)

> Object initializers let you assign values to any *accessible fields* or properties of an object at creation time without having to invoke a constructor followed by *lines of assignment statements*.

Comment: Seems that they need to fix initializer syntax to actually initialize, then. The key part here is "at creation time".

Comment: @Puppy it is always good exercise trying to come up with decent specification for feature you want. If you decide to try it out don't forget that properties are not fields - so one need to come up with a way of not being able to use `set` properties from outside of the object while at the same time allowing initializer syntax.

Answer (score 2):

> "readonly fields can't be set except in a constructor or variable
>   initializer, despite the fact that it's clearly a goddamn variable
>   initializer."

No, it is not. "variable initializer" is this:

```
public class Class
{
    public int Property1 { get; } = 5;
}
```

**The " `= 5`" is the variable initializer**, because you're initializing a variable just in the same place of the definition.

See [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645757(v=vs.71).aspx).

What you're calling "*variable* initializer" is actually "*object* initializer", which is just syntactic sugar for:

1. Calling a constructor
2. Set OUTSIDE OF THE CONSTRUCTOR a list of properties.

For example:

```
var c = new Class("hello", 4.5) //<-- this is the constructor
{
    Prop1 = new DataTable(),  //<-- from here you're outside the constructor,
    Prop2 = new Point(2,3),   //    so you can't set an only "{ get; }" property.
    Prop3 = 0.2,
};
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, the reason you want to be able to initialize read-only fields is to avoid mix-ups where a constructor with two compatible types was called in the wrong order, right?

So while other questions explained nicely why this isn't currently possible, there's a helpful technique you can use to minimize this problem while still using the same constructors - [named arguments](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx). C# allows you to explicitly state the name of the parameters, and then specify them in any order:

```
var myClass = new Class(prop2: interface2Instance, prop1: interface1Instance);
```

This will compile, and be explicit in what value is passed to what parameter.

Of course, you can't enforce this requirement in the code itself, but it *can* be part of your coding style guidelines, if you find that you have many constructors with compatible types that need clarification.