# string created from variable in c#

Tags: c#, string, variables

Is it possible to to define a string from a variable where the string does NOT have quotations. Example:

```
public class aclass
{
    public string athing;
}

public void example(string thing)
{
    aclass thing = new aclass();
}
```

The string thing can't be put into `aclass thing = new aclass();` normaly.
Is there anyway to do it?

Comment: You need to declare constructor with `string` as argument, e.g. `public aclass(string value) { athing = value; }` before using `aclass thing = new aclass("somestring");`.

Comment: Actually I understand the question. Unfortunately C# does not have atom object as Erlang.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a constructor

```
void Main()
{
    CreateExampleObject("testing");
}

public class Example
{
    // This is a constructor that requires a string as an argument
    public Example(string text)
    {
        this.Text = text;
    }

    public string Text { get; set; }
}

public void CreateExampleObject(string text)
{
    Example example = new Example(text);

    Console.WriteLine(example.Text);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this using many way but generally standard way is using constructor 
please refer this link for better understanding.

[C# : assign data to properties via constructor vs. instantiating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19138195/c-sharp-assign-data-to-properties-via-constructor-vs-instantiating)

Answer (score 0):

You have to ways of setting fields/property value of an object.

First is to do it through the constructor, as mentioned in other answer.

Second can be implmeneted in various ways:

1. Expose public property making field privte:

   ```
   public class aclass
   {
       private string _athing;
       public string Athing 
       {
               get { return _athing; }
               set { _athing = value; }
       }
   }

   public void example(string thing)
   {
       aclass aclass = new aclass();
       aclass.Athing = thing;
   }
   ```

Or even shorter, you could use property:

```
public class aclass
{
    public string Athing {get; set; }
}
```

2. Using your implementation, you make your field public, so you can set it easily:

   ```
   public void example(string thing)
   {
       aclass aclass = new aclass();
       aclass.athing = thing;
   }
   ```

But it doesn't comply with OOP encapsulation principle.