# thread safe construction with attribute assignment

Tags: c#, multithreading, constructor

from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers

> ```
> class Cat
> {
>     // Auto-implemented properties.
>     public int Age { get; set; }
>     public string Name { get; set; }
> }
>
> Cat cat = new Cat { Age = 10, Name = "Fluffy" };
> ```
>
> The object initializers syntax allows you to create an instance, and
>   **after** that it assigns the newly created object, with its assigned properties, to the variable in the assignment.

vs https://stackoverflow.com/a/19138412/432976

> ```
> var albumData = new Album 
> {
>      Name = "Albumius",
>      Artist = "Artistus",
>      Year = 2013
>  };
> ```
>
> is syntactic shorthand for this equivalent code:
>
> ```
> var albumData = new Album();
> albumData.Name = "Albumius";
> albumData.Artist = "Artistus";
> albumData.Year = 2013;
> ```
>
> The two are identical after compilation.

Question:
is this stype of construction + assignment thread safe?
(ie, could another thread reading cat see the Cat between when it was created, and when Age and Name are assigned)?

The first seems to say it is, as it is after the properties are assigned, the variable gets assigned (the threadsafe order), the second says that at a compiled code level, the order is different.

if the second is true, is the following code sufficient to avoid the race condition of another thread seeing a half constructed cat?

```
var myNewCat = new Cat { Age = 10, Name = "Fluffy" };
sharedCat = myNewCat;
```

I realise that there are secondary race conditions here concerning if other threads see the oldCat or the newCat, but in this situation my only concern is that other threads must see a complete Cat, not a half constructed one.

Comment: It seems that the accepted answer is wrong: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19138231/2141621 which ends up in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9753256/resurrection-difference-in-using-object-initializer/9753319#9753319

Comment: It appears to be thread-safe (i.e. your first quote, not your second, is correct). https://dotnetfiddle.net/iOt7RP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the following example class

```
public class Cat
{
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

## C# 2.0 Style

Code

```
var cat1 = new Cat();
cat1.Age = 10;
cat1.Name = "Fluffy";
```

Generates the following [IL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Intermediate_Language) code (inspected using [.Net Reflector](https://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/reflector/))

```
L_000c: newobj instance void ConsoleApp1.Cat::.ctor()
L_0011: stloc.0 
L_0012: ldloc.0 
L_0013: ldc.i4.s 10
L_0015: callvirt instance void ConsoleApp1.Cat::set_Age(int32)
L_001a: nop 
L_001b: ldloc.0 
L_001c: ldstr "Fluffy"
L_0021: callvirt instance void ConsoleApp1.Cat::set_Name(string)
L_0026: nop
```

This basically creates the variable instance and its available (from [**stloc.0**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.stloc(v=vs.110).aspx)), so at that point it is available for another thread to pick it up in that state if it was exposed.

> Answer is no this version is not thread safe

## C# 3.0 Style

Since C# 3 onwards we can do what is called [Object Initializers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers).

Code

```
var cat1 = new Cat { Age = 10, Name = "Fluffy" };
```

Generates the following IL code

```
L_000c: newobj instance void ConsoleApp1.Cat::.ctor()
L_0011: dup 
L_0012: ldc.i4.s 10
L_0014: callvirt instance void ConsoleApp1.Cat::set_Age(int32)
L_0019: nop 
L_001a: dup 
L_001b: ldstr "Fluffy"
L_0020: callvirt instance void ConsoleApp1.Cat::set_Name(string)
L_0025: nop 
L_0026: stloc.0
```

The main difference here is the instance of the class is never pulled off the evaluation stack as it uses [**dup**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.dup(v=vs.110).aspx) until its all done then does **stloc.0** last.

> Answer is this method **is thread-safe**

Answer (score 2):

@JonSkeet [says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9753319/883299) the equivalent code introduces a temp variable.

```
var tmp = new Album();
tmp.Name = "Albumius";
tmp.Artist = "Artistus";
tmp.Year = 2013;
var albumData = tmp;
```

Or for the Cat

```
var tmp = new Cat();
tmp.Age = 10;
tmp.Name = "Fluffy";
Cat cat = tmp;
```

So if the reference assignment is threadsafe, then the object initialiser would be threadsafe. Right?

Answer (score -1):

A piece of code is thread-safe if it only manipulates shared data structures in a manner that guarantees safe execution by multiple threads at the same time.
In the example you have provided as is, there is no shared state, as the instance is assigned to a local variable. Hence, either way (and yes, they're the same) is always thread-safe:

```
var albumData = new Album 
{
     Name = "Albumius",
     Artist = "Artistus",
     Year = 2013
 };
```

The situation changes, as soon as the variable being assigned is not local to the method it's in (a field of a class for example):

```
class TestClass
{
  private Album album;

  public void TestAssignment(string name)
  {
    // Here I'm using this style of property assignment to make it very explicit why it's not thread-safe
    this.album = new Album();
    this.album.Name = name;
    ...
  }
}
```

As you can see, the `TestAssignment()` method now can be called from different threads at the same time. Depending on which thread will execute each line, different values will be assigned to the album instance as well as it's name.
In this case, it would make sense to think about thread-safety mechanisms.

Hope this helps to clarify the difference.